# Playing 3d chess

Tags: learning

I have a quite simple question: I was watching the Big Bang theory and I was wondering if 3d chess was possible? And how us it similar and different to regular chess

Comment: See http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5397/about-the-3d-chess-they-play-on-star-trek